# How to modify input from ifconfig in awk

Tags: shell, awk, ifconfig

**Edit:**
Sample output of ifconfig

```
enp2s0f1: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 2540  bytes 207824 (202.9 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2540  bytes 207824 (202.9 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask xxx.xxx.xxx.x  broadcast xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
        inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1413004  bytes 634560717 (605.1 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 279420  bytes 36406046 (34.7 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I have this nice written code by other helpful user and I need to modify output of it.
I must admit I have a hard time doing it.

```
ifconfig |
awk '
/^[[:alnum:]]+: / {
   n = $1
   p = 1
}
n !~ /^lo/ && /^[[:blank:]]+(inet|ether) / {
   if (p) {
      print n
      p = 0
   }
   print $1, $2
}'
```

Here's correct output from it:

```
enp2s0f1:
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0:
inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

And this is how I need it to be modifed:

(with created columns inet_name, ip_address, mac_address)

```
inet_name ip_address           mac_address
enp2s0f1:                      ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0:   inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

Comment: Perhaps [AWK Arrays Explained with 5 Practical Examples](https://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/03/awk-arrays-explained-with-5-practical-examples/) will give you some ideas to work with.

Comment: Please, post the sample output of `ifconfig`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may try this `awk`:

```sh
ifconfig |
awk -v OFS='\t' 'BEGIN {ip=mac=" "; print "inet_name", "ip_ddress", "mac_address"} /^[[:alnum:]]+: / {if (inet) {print inet, ip, mac; ip=mac=" "; inet=""} if ($1 !~ /^lo/) inet=$1} inet && /^[[:blank:]]+inet / {ip=$1 " " $2} inet && /^[[:blank:]]+ether / {mac=$1 " " $2} END {if (inet) print inet, ip, mac}' | column -t -s $'\t'

inet_name  ip_ddress             mac_address
enp2s0f1:                        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
wlp3s0:    inet xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
ifconfig |
awk -v OFS='\t' '
# set output field separator to tab
BEGIN {
   # initialize ip and mac variables
   ip = mac = " "
   print header record
   print "inet_name", "ip_ddress", "mac_address"
}
/^[[:alnum:]]+: / {            # if no blank at start
   if (inet) {                 # print full record if not first time
      print inet, ip, mac
      ip = mac = " "           # reset variables
      inet = ""
   }
   if ($1 !~ /^lo/)            # if not starting with "lo"
      inet = $1                # save inet name in var inet
}
inet && /^[[:blank:]]+inet / { # if inet is set and we have inet after spaces
   ip = $1 " " $2              # save $1 " " $2 in ip variable
}
inet && /^[[:blank:]]+ether / {#  if inet is set and we have ether after spaces
   mac = $1 " " $2             # save $1 " " $2 in mac variable

}
END {
   if (inet)                   # if inet is not blank
      print inet, ip, mac      # print full record
}
' | column -t -s $'\t'
```

- `column` comman has been used for tabular output.

Comment: Wow! ...and here you are to save the day again! Thanks man it's still too complicated to me could you place comments like last time? :D

Comment: Sure, adding it now

Comment: Big thanks! I will dive right into it and I will analize it to better understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of parsing the output of `ifconfig` which is not a reliable API data exchange, you could use the `ip` tool instead with its `-j` or `-json` option to output JSON formatted answer that can be reliably parsed with a tool like `jq` or any programming language with a JSON parser.

Here it is as a one-liner:

```sh
ip -json addr show |
  jq -r '"name\tip_address\tmac_address", ( .[] | if (.addr_info | length) > 0 then .ifname + "\t" + (.addr_info[] | select(.family=="inet")).local + "\t" + .address else empty end )'
```

Or commented stand-alone `jq` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S jq -rf

# Print header line
"name\tip_address\tmac_address",
(
  # Stream all results array
  .[] |

  # If interface has a non-empty addr_info array
  if (.addr_info | length) > 0
  then
    # Print interface name as first column
    .ifname + "\t" + (
    # Print ipv4 address as second column
      .addr_info[] | select(.family=="inet")
    ).local + "\t" +
    # Print mac address as third column
    .address
  else
  # Do nothing if interface has no ip address
    empty
  end
)
```

Example output:

```
name    ip_address      mac_address
lo      127.0.0.1       00:00:00:00:00:00
enp4s0  192.168.1.10    00:24:1d:00:00:00
virbr0  192.168.122.1   52:54:00:00:00:00
```

Comment: Thanks that's helpful too. But I need to do it the hard way. :(